# Remove unneeded values from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, data-cleaning

I have a PHP script that loops across various tables of a database to generate scores.

I don't know in advance how many results will accumulate or how many users. 
So I loop through the data and collect the datasets into a one dimensional array, as follows:

```
Daniel Kelleher,1,0,1,0,Bill Bixby,1,0,1,0,Daniel Kelleher,2,0,2,0,Daniel Kelleher,3,1,2,0,Bill Bixby,2,1,1,0,Daniel Kelleher,4,1,2,1
```

You can see the pattern of 5 values looping through the array - name,int,int,int,int. In this instance there are two users - Daniel Kelleher and Bill Bixby.

I only need the last instance of data for each user e.g. Daniel Kelleher,4,1,2,1 and Bill Bixby,2,1,1,0.

How would I strip the unwanted values and finish with an array as 'Bill Bixby,2,1,1,0,Daniel Kelleher,4,1,2,1'?

Comment: Post original array it looks like a string

Comment: also post the source where the array is generating

Comment: use unset() to achieve this

Comment: Hi @Uchiha, is a string here to simplify the contents of the array visually.

Comment: It will be better to put your code here, from where you are generating this either as a string or as an array.then only possible to give accurate solution.thanks

Comment: Its really difficult to cisualize how your array looks like instead just `print_r` your array and post that output over here @AdamFletcher

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('Daniel Kelleher',1,0,1,0,'Bill Bixby',1,0,1,0,'Daniel Kelleher',2,0,2,0,'Daniel Kelleher',3,1,2,0,'Bill Bixby',2,1,1,0,'Daniel Kelleher',4,1,2,1);

$temp = array();
$chunk = array_chunk($array,5);  // make array of arrays with 5 items
foreach($chunk as $item)
  $temp[$item[0]] = $item;

var_dump($temp);
// array(2) { 
//       ["Daniel Kelleher"] => array("Daniel Kelleher", 4, 1, 2, 1)
//       ["Bill Bixby"] => array("Bill Bixby", 2, 1, 1 0)
// }

// if you want plain array

$result = array();
foreach($temp as $item)  
   $result = array_merge($result, $item);
var_dump($result);   
// array("Daniel Kelleher", 4, 1, 2, 1, "Bill Bixby", 2, 1, 1, 0)
```